# Call appropriate child class 'items' property

Tags: c#, inheritance

May I know how can I call appropriate child class 'items' property when PaginatedItemsDto (parent) was called in controller. FYI, there are two child class forPaginatedItemsDto, each with  'items' property of its own. I need to be calling the correct 'Items' property that was sent from backend.

Please read comments specified in controller class below to understand better. 'Items' property gets lost when mapping was done in controller. I receive only 'skip' and 'take'. Mapping does not work with child class. Thank you.

I am returning 'Items' of GroupedPaginatedItems.

DataProvider class:

```
 returnData = new GroupedPaginatedItems
    {
        Items = result,
        Skip = 0,
        Take = result.Count()
    };
```

Controller class:

```
public async Task<PaginatedItemsDto> GetItems()
 {
    // here I receive correct appropriate child 'Items' and 'skip', 'take' properties
    result = await _itemService.GetItemsAsync(); 
    // Here is the issue, 'Items' property gets lost here. I receive only 'skip' and 'take'. So mapping does not work with child class.     
    return _mapper.Map<PaginatedItemsDto>(result); 
 }
```

Backened:

PaginatedItems class:

```
public class PaginatedItems
{
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    public int Take { get; set; }
    
}

public class GroupedPaginatedItems : PaginatedItems
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Item>>>? Items { get; set; }
}

public class FlatPaginatedItems : PaginatedItems
{
    public IEnumerable<Item>? Items { get; set; }
}
```

Frontend:

PaginatedItemsDTO class:

```
 // Will using typeDiscriminator as below help call appropriate child?
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(GroupedPaginatedItemsDto), typeDiscriminator: "GroupedItem")]  
public class PaginatedItemsDto
{
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    public int Take { get; set; }

public class FlatPaginatedItemsDto : PaginatedItemsDto
{
    [JsonInclude]
    public List<DetailsDto> Items { get; set; } = new();
}
public class GroupedPaginatedItemsDto : PaginatedItemsDto
{
    [JsonInclude]
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<DetailsDto>>>? Items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how inheritance works in the C#, you can't map in `PaginatedItemsDto` and expect to have Items mapped. You should map into `FlatPaginatedItemsDto` then expect to have Items. Indeed that mapped value can be assigned to their base class `PaginatedItemsDto` but it is still `FlatPaginatedItemsDto`.

So your items are not lost - behavior is expected (only thing mapped are properties from your PaginatedItemsDto), your inheritance logic is wrong.

For example this is possible :

```
PaginatedItemsDto items = _mapper.Map<FlatPaginatedItemsDto>(result); 

if (items is FlatPaginatedItemsDto) // this is true
```

To return right mapped value from your contoller you can use `switch`:

```
    return result switch
    {
      FlatPaginatedItems flatItems => _mapper.Map<FlatPaginatedItemsDto>(flatItems),
      GroupedPaginatedItems grouppedItems => _mapper.Map<GroupedPaginatedItemsDto>(grouppedItems),
      _ => throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown type") 
    }
```

Useful [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-inheritance/)

Comment: Thank you, the problem is I wouldn't know which child class 'items' property is returned from backend. So I can't harcode as 'FlatPaginatedItemsDto' or 'GroupedPaginatedItemsDto' in the controller. Can you suggest me any other option I can use, as items returned (is dynamic) can be from any of the two child classes.

Comment: updated my answer , but answer from @CanYksel can be applied also.

Comment: Says System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Shared.Dtos.PaginatedItemsDto' to type 'Shared.Dtos.GroupedPaginatedItemsDto'.'

Comment: can you share more of your code and update the question ? Just to see where do you get that exception

Comment: Controller return type is PaginatedItemsDto ->  public async Task<PaginatedItemsDto> GetItems()...  Says cannot implicitly convert GroupedPaginatedItemsDto TO PaginatedItemsDto

Comment: Is it possible to use typeDiscriminator as below on PaginatedItemsDto (parent) to call the appropriate child class? Thank you.
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(GroupedPaginatedItemsDto), typeDiscriminator: "GroupedItem")]

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the actual type of result like this:

```
if (result is GroupedPaginatedItems groupedResult)
    return _mapper.Map<GroupedPaginatedItemsDto>(groupedResult);
else if (result is FlatPaginatedItems flatResult)
    return _mapper.Map<FlatPaginatedItemsDto>(flatResult);
else throw new Exception("The result type not found");
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Shows error as "Nullabilty of reference types in value of type 'GroupedPaginatedItemsDto' does not match target type 'PaginatedItemsDto' "